# Package existing war in ear via maven

Tags: maven, build, weblogic, war, ear

1. I have a war file (binary - no source code) which I want to insert
   in my project
2. My project is built into EAR file on Weblogic
3. So, I want this external war file to be packaged within my project EAR and I 
   can HIT this war file externally.
   IMPORTANT :

   4. I cannot deploy the war separately
   5. I cannot build the war file code within my project code
   6. I cannot add war as a dependency in my project pom.xml (It is not found by maven)

Answer (score 1):

Actually you *can* add it as dependency in your POM. But you need to install it first into your local repository, i.e. use `mvn install:install-file` to put it into your local repository.

Even better, if your company runs a Nexus or Artifactory, you can upload it there.